# Why doesn't this vector assignment work?

Tags: c++, stdvector, assignment-operator, copy-assignment

Similar Questions:

- [STL vector reserve() and copy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128535/stl-vector-reserve-and-copy)
- [std::vector reserve() and push_back() is faster than resize() and array index, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461276/stdvector-reserve-and-push-back-is-faster-than-resize-and-array-index-w)
- [std::vector::resize() vs. std::vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029299/stdvectorresize-vs-stdvectorreserve)

---

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<vector<int> > vvi;
  vvi.resize(1);
  vvi[0].reserve(1);
  vvi[0][0] = 1;

  vector<int> vi = vvi[0];

  cout << vi[0]; // cout << vvi[0][0]; works

  return 0;
}
```

This gives me a seg fault, and I can't tell why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 vvi[0].reserve(1);
 vvi[0][0] = 1;
```

You need `resize`, not `reserve`.

Accessng an element `i` where `i>=v.size()` is undefined behavior. `reserve` affects `capacity`, not `size`.

If I were to go into the practical aspect, I might speculate that perhaps you might get away with the assignment `vvi[0][0] = 1;` (in Release Mode, at least). But the main practical problem lies here

```
vector<int> vi = vvi[0];
```

The problem is that `vvi[0]`'s size is 0, so `vi`'s internal array size is 0, regardless of `vvi[0]`'s capacity. That's I think where you get the seg fault, after you

```
cout << vi[0]; // cout << vvi[0][0]; works
```

But that's all speculations. The correct answer to your question is that this

```
vvi[0].reserve(1);
vvi[0][0] = 1;
```

already has undefined behavior, and no further considerations are required.

Comment: Additionally, `vii[0][0]` "works" because the vector object in `vii[0]` did make sure the array would have an element at offset `0`, but the capacity is not required to survive the copy construction.

Comment: @bitmask: I was editing to say about that simlutaneously with your comment! :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the T; [Fastest Gun In The West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533/168610)