# void Print(vector<string>) function is not printing

Tags: c++, string, vector, stdvector, cout

I made a function for printing a vector using interators. The function is part of program meant to copy a vector of strings to another vector of strings. The original function was a simple for loop using the .at() member function and that worked. So, I am not sure what's wrong with this one. 
The code:

```
#include <string>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print(vector<string> &v);

int main() {
    ifstream inFS;
    inFS.open("sentence.txt");

    vector<string> wordList; vector<string> newVect; 
    string s;
    while (inFS >> s) {
        wordList.push_back(s);
    }

    copy(wordList.begin(), wordList.end(), newVect.begin());
    print(wordList);
    print(newVect);
}


void print(vector<string> &v) {
    for (vector<string>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++) {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The output:

```
C:\Users\westt\Documents\PROJECT>a.exe

C:\Users\westt\Documents\PROJECT>
```

Comment: Before `copy` you need to ensure that `newVect` has enough elements. Add `newVect.resize(wordList.size());` before `copy`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple change to initialize the newVect.  As the comment noted, you could also resize() newVect

```
#include <string>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print(vector<string> &v);

int main() {
    ifstream inFS;
    inFS.open("sentence.txt");

    vector<string> wordList; 
    string s;
    while (inFS >> s) {
        wordList.push_back(s);
    }

    vector<string> newVect(wordList);
    print(wordList);
    print(newVect);
}


void print(vector<string> &v) {
    for (vector<string>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++) {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you it worked. What was wrong with it?

Comment: The copy was not right.  The proper use is non-intiuitive, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128535/stl-vector-reserve-and-copy

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I just did. Thanks again.